# Rails How to get 2 objects using join and where on ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ransack

i'm trying to use ransack to get two associated objects

relationship

> 1. Proback belongs to user
> 2. Proback belongs to product
> 3. Product has_many probacks
> 4. User has_many probacks

but the logs show:

> ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid (wrong number of bind variables
>   (1 for 2) in: products.id = ? and users.id = ?)

```
 @q = Proback.joins(:product,:user).where('products.id = ? and users.id =? ', @product.id,@user.id).ransack(params[:q])
```

someone please can spare a hint?

Comment: can you explain relationships among these models?

Comment: @mayank, sure! just a moment!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@q = Proback.joins(:product, :user).where('products.id = ? and users.id = ?', @product.id, @user.id).ransack(params[:q])
```

You are missing `= ?`.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and recreate the scenarios but I didn't get any such error.
I also generated the error you've mentioned.

> ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid (wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: products.id = ? and users.id = ?)

It generated when I pass more than one binding variable or less in where clause.Please retry your code and make sure that binding variables matches '?' :

```
result = Proback.joins(:product, :user).where('products.id = ? and users.id = ?', @product.id, @user.id)

@q= result.ransack(params[:q])
```

By doing this error differentiation will be easy